# Website Scraping with Jsoup beginner

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

Im attempting to use jsoup to scrape a website. Ive extracted a table row into an Elements object using the class ".eventTableRow" in the source HTML, but im unsure how I can access the individual cells. Im attempting to get the data in the cells as highlighted with a box in the below image :

```
Elements row = doc.select(.eventTableRow);
System.out.println(row);
//prints similar to below image :
```

http://postimg.org/image/blc5ob74b/38f0a081/

I couldnt upload the image becasue I dont have 10 reputation

I understand for many of you this is rudimentary and I will surely get links to jsoup documentation, but ive been reading and trying for a few hours and can't get it to work for me.

For instance i have tried :

```
Elements result = race.select("[attr^=712]"); 
//im attempting to find all atributes beginning 712 but it doesn't work

Elements result = race.select(".o bgc co"); 
//im attempting to find the cells with this class
```

and many others, I don't really understand how to implement the instructions in the documentation, its hard for me to understand and I cant find any basic tutorials.

Would learning about some other area help me understand the jsoup documentation better, maybe XML, DOM, Parsing HTML etc these are things i have been searching google for.

Any help appreciated.

p.s If someone made an idiots guide to using jsoup for scraping or scraping using java in general, im sure it would be very popular.

Comment: You could loop all TD elements and read only elements you were looking for.

Comment: agreed, but how would I structure the loop. I don't understand the "syntax" that would allow me to do it. am i looping childs? nodes? I been reading a lot but can't make sence of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all TD elements, here is working example:

```
package my.test;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<table><tr class='eventTableRow'><td id='1' class='class1'>value1</td><td id='2' class='class2'>value2</td><td id='3' class='class3'>value3</td></tr></table>");
        Elements row = doc.select(".eventTableRow td");
        Iterator<Element> iterator = row.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Element element = iterator.next();
            String id = element.attr("id");
            String classes = element.attr("class");
            String value = element.text();
            System.out.println("Id : " + id + ", classes : " + classes+ ", value : " + value);
        }
    }

}
```

And it outputs:

```
Id : 1, classes : class1, value : value1
Id : 2, classes : class2, value : value2
Id : 3, classes : class3, value : value3
```

Comment: Thx so much, worked a treat :) Can i ask would it be possible to explain this line - '  Iterator<Element> iterator = row.listIterator();' - i tried searching jsoup docs but can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sketch:

```
    for(Element f : e.select("[id^=code_]")) {
        System.out.println("printed out links: " + f.select("*").text());
    }
```

Basic idea is for each element which has an id which begins with 'code_' select everything in that element and print it.